# Drain pump on dishwasher running backwards

Tags: drain, dishwasher, pump

I have a GE GDT665SFN0DS dishwasher and the other day it stopped pumping out the drain. I checked for debris and clogs, nothing. I did notice that when I ran it without the filter and screen installed for testing, the little backflow valve would be popped out when I opened the door back up to check. I also noticed that when full of water and you cycle the power it will run the drain pump with the door open. It is at this moment that I noticed that the pump is pushing the water back into the dishwasher and not out the drain hose. I do believe that this pump motor is AC and is not reversible as far as direction is concerned, but the water is bubbling out of the drain hole, you can put your finger on it and it has pressure! What is the issue? Is the pump bad? Is the drain line clogged and the water has no place to exit? Are there gnomes living inside and making my life fun! Thanks for any help you might be able to provide. The pumps are cheap enough so I'm just going to order 2 anyways for stock.

Comment: If it has worked before, check for clogs.

Comment: There is a small chance that the capacitor on the pump has failed, if it has one.

Comment: Old type of diswasher motor is reversible. One direction water in, another out.  Reversed by changing polarity of starting coil. Some relays may be gone.